# File handling in a chrome extension using NPAPI (npapi-file-io)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, file-io, npapi

I'm writing a chrome extension that needs to be able to access the file system for reading/writing/listing files. To do this, I've been trying to use [npapi-file-io](http://code.google.com/p/npapi-file-io/), but I've had no success getting it to work, as there's no documentation.

I've specified the relevant dll/sos in the extension's manifest like this:

```
{
  "name": "npapi-file-io-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Test extension for npapi-file-io project",
  "plugins": [{"path": "npapi-file-io-32.dll", "public": true},{"path": "npapi-file-io-32.so", "public": true},{"path": "npapi-file-io-64.so", "public": true}]
}
```

and I'm loading in and trying to use the plugin like this:

```
<p><embed type="application/x-npapi-file-io" id="plugin"/></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.getElementById("plugin").getPlatform());
</script>
```

but I just get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method 'getPlatform'
```

on Linux Mint.

Am I missing something here? Are there any good examples of NPAPI embedding I could work my way up from? Is there some alternative plugin I could use for file handling?

Comment: It doesn't look like you've listed a Mac plugin in the extension manifest, so it's not surprising that it doesn't work there.

Comment: @smorgan Note it also does not work on Linux.

Comment: You can try to find out if your plugin is registered and enabled by MIME type. Please look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Basics#Checking_Plug-ins_by_MIME_Type for guidance

Comment: Does it work if you try [installing the plugin publically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Development_Overview#Install_to_Known_Locations_on_Linux_and_Mac), does it work? That way you should at least be able to conclude whether it's an issue with the plugin or the packaging.